# Error with find and activate functions in excel with vba

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having a really bad time trying to understand why I get an error which I thing should not appear.
I'm using Office 2007. I have two sheets in Excel, "Ver" and "Encargado", in "Ver" sheet I have one cell in which to put a number and then I press one button. The code inside the button is:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   Dim buscar As Range
   dato = Range("b2").Value
   If dato = "" Then Exit Sub

   Sheets("Encargado").Select
   Set buscar = Range("b2:b12").Find(What:=dato, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows)

   If Not buscar Is Nothing Then
      buscar.Activate
      ActiveCell.Offset(, -1).Copy Destination:=Ver.Cells(4, 2)
      Sheets("Ver").Select
   Else
      Sheets("Ver").Select
      MsgBox "Encargado no encontrado"
      Exit Sub
   End If
End Sub
```

In "Encargado" sheet and inside the range b2:b12 there are only numbers beetwen 101 and 111, and when I put the number 117 as an input (for example) I think it should get into the else part as it shouldn't have found any coincidence, but it gets into the if part, why? and I get an error saying "Error en el método activate de la clase Range" (As you noticed I am using Office in spanish, and programming as well with spanish variables). When I run line by line the error appears in the line "buscar.Activate". Does anyone know where is the error? In the case you want to see it, here is the file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/j1b39fqy971n7lf/Todo.xlsm Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have not defined  the sheet in find function so its referring ver sheet. Use this code.

```
   Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   Dim buscar As Range

   'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

   dato = Range("b2").Value

   If dato = "" Then Exit Sub
    Set buscar = Sheets("Encargado").Range("b2:b12").Find(What:=dato, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchOrder:=xlByRows)
   If Not buscar Is Nothing Then
      'Encargado.Cells.Find(What:=Ver.Cells(2, 2), After:=Range("b2"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Select
      'desplazamiento en fila, desplazamiento en columna, positivo: hacia abajo, hacia la derecha
      'buscar.Activate
      c = buscar.Row

     Sheets("Encargado").Range("a" & c).Copy
     Sheets("Ver").Range("b4").PasteSpecial


   Else
      Sheets("Ver").Select
      MsgBox "Encargado no encontrado"
      Exit Sub
   End If
   'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I've used this code, and now it works when the input is not found, it correctly shows the message "Encargado no encontrado", but doesn't work when I put one input that should be found, it should write in "Ver" sheet the name of the Encargado, but it doesn't write anything.

Comment: Hi, I have updated new code. Please use this and get back to me if still you are facing any problem.

Comment: It worked perfectly, thank you very much! One last question, do you know why my first idea of activating the cell in which the "dato" was found and then moving to the left and copy didn't work in this problem? The problem was always in the function activate.

Comment: buscar is a object thats why its not working. But i am not sure about this. Can you please accept the answer. ?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** As pointed out in the comments below, the `Range` object **DOES** have an `.Activate` method: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837085(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837085%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

<strike>`buscar` is a `Range` object, which does not have an `Activate` method.</strike> The following should get you where you're going, but out of curiosity -- have you looked into Excel's built-in `=VLOOKUP` functionality? It might save you from requiring VBA here...

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim TerritorioNum As Long, LastRow As Long
Dim TerritorioRange As Range, FoundRange As Range
Dim VerSheet As Worksheet, EncSheet As Worksheet

'set references up-front
Set VerSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ver")
Set EncSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Encargado")
With EncSheet
    LastRow = .Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    Set TerritorioRange = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LastRow, 2))
End With
TerritorioNum = VerSheet.Cells(2, 2).Value

'find the territory number
Set FoundRange = TerritorioRange.Find(TerritorioNum)
If FoundRange Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox ("Encargado no encontrado")
    Exit Sub
Else
    VerSheet.Cells(4, 2) = EncSheet.Cells(FoundRange.Row, FoundRange.Column - 1).Value
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Range objects **do** have an activate method. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837085(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: Shame on me! Thank you @DavidZemens for pointing out my mistake in the above